# OnItemClickListener or something in ListPreference

Tags: java, android, listpreference

first, I am German and sorry if my english is not so good. I will try to describe my problem so good as possible.
I have a ListPreference in which the users should choose their class. When the users click on any entry they will join a topic in Firebase. My problem is the "when the users click on any entry". I don't know how to do this that if the user click on any entry that anything will happen. I have already tried this:

```
ListPreference pref_klassen_list_key = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_klassen_list_key");

pref_klassen_list_key.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                return true;
            }
        });
```

and the same with the onPreferenceClick. But both methods were called at the wrong time: 1. Choose the Class 2. Close the ListPreference 3. Open the ListPreference again --> onPreferenceChange is called and 4. Choose class again --> onPreferenceClick is called, but I tried to show the accepted class with toasts and they showed the class choosed in 1. I hope you understood my problem. I want to have a method which is called when I do 1. Here are my activities:
1. SettingsActivity.java

```
package main.faseflex.de.fgnapp;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


        ListPreference pref_klassen_list_key = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_klassen_list_key");


        pref_klassen_list_key.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                String prefList = sharedPreferences.getString("pref_klassen_list_key", "0");

                int integer = Integer.parseInt(prefList);


                if (integer == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 5.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 5.2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 5.3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 6.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 6.2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 5) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 7.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 7.2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 7) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 8.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 8) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 8.2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 9) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 9.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 9.2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 11) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 10", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (integer == 12) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Klasse 11", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
        android:title="Es sind noch nicht alle Funktionen komplett implementiert."
        android:selectable="false" />

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Allgemeines">

        <Preference
            android:selectable="false"
            android:summary="Hier werden später allgemeine Einstellungen stehen." />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Benachrichtigungen">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="pref_about_checkbox_key"
            android:title="Benachrichtigungen erhalten"
            android:summary="Benachrichtigung bei Änderung im Stundenplan"/>

        <ListPreference
            android:title="Klasse auswählen"
            android:summary="%s"
            android:key="pref_klassen_list_key"
            android:dependency="pref_about_checkbox_key"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/pref_klassen_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_klassen_values" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Über die App">

        <Preference
            android:summary="Danke für dein Feedback!"
            android:title="Feedback"
            android:key="pref_about_feedback_key" />

        <Preference
            android:summary="@string/versionshort"
            android:title="Version"
            android:key="@string/pref_about_version_key"/>

        <Preference
            android:summary=""
            android:title="Impressum"
            android:key="pref_about_impressum_key"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Entwickler-Einstellungen">

        <Preference
            android:title="Daten zu Benachrichtigungen"
            android:summary="technische Informationen zu Push-Benachrichtigungen"
            android:key="pref_fcmtoken_key" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am searching anything like the OnItemSelectedListener from a spinner. Say if any other file is needed or you don't understand anything. I am looking forward to read your replies.